# How to push the "clear color" onto the attribute stack

Tags: opengl, attributes, colors, stack

I'm trying to use glPushAttrib to push the "clear color" (set using glClearColor) onto the attribute stack. The problem is: I'm not sure which flag to send to glPushAttrib.

Background: I normally use glClearColor to set my app's "background" color. However, in a few places I have to change the glClearColor to clear out a texture that I'm drawing into. I want to use the attrib stack to push and then pop the "background" color so it doesn't get messed up.

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious thing to do is always call glClearColor before each glClear, but I'm trying to reduce state changes and gl calls in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [glPushAttrib](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml) this is:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now: "Color mode and index mode clear values" (face-palm). Thanks!

Comment: In general, do you think it's better to use glPushAttrib/glPopAttrib, or to just re-set the glClearColor every frame?

Comment: I think it is always better to keep track of the state by yourself: glPushAttrib does change a lot of other parameters.